# Generate report based on search asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Currently I'm learning how to generate report using asp.net. I want my result which display on a gridview to be generated to report after search.

I tried this for the Report Viewer button but it doesn't work.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ReportViewer1.Reset()

    Dim rptSrc As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", GetData())
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptSrc)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc"

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Anyone can recommend a tutorial about generating reports based on search or who can provide code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on click method use this code

`String query = Select * from members where member_id=""+txtProductID.Text;
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, sCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        sCon.Open();
        oda.Fill(imageDataSet.Tables["DataTable1"]);
        sCon.Close();`

```
    //Set Report Source
    ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
    crystalReport.SetDataSource(imageDataSet);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
```